# Wordpress Custom Template page not displaying

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Unable to get my custom created page in page attributes Templates, rest all the pages are still shown in the dropdown but new created page is not listed. I have created a custom page in PHP and uploaded it in `wp-content->themes->my-theme` in the root directory.

Kindly assist, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your template file name is like page_{template-name} and not page-{template-name}.

Also add this at the beginning of the template.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

Check this out for more details https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: This fixed it perfectly, thank you! Specially the naming of the file is very important

Answer (score 0):

Add at the beginning of your custom page:

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Template name
*/

?>
```

The second template name will the name of your template

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have already added the name of the file in a same way. still not working.